# How to get hierarchical data

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data

I want to execute a SQL sentence, there are two tables

```
Table Name      Description
*********      *********
H_person    Employee Data
Modelorg    Position Data
```

I want to write an sql that shows "who is connected to whom". In h_person table

```
Fıeld Name      Description
*********      *********
p_no        Employee ID
P_ad        Employee Name
P_soyad Employee Surname
P_pzsyn Employee Position ID
```

In Modelorg Table

```
Fıeld Name      Description
*********      *********
Pozkod      Position ID
Pozad       Position Name
USTPOZKOD   the upper position (POZKOD connected to USTPOZKOD)
```

USTPOZKOD is also the POZKOD at the same time,there is a hierarchial connection.

1. I would like to form a report shows person ID, Name,  Surname, Position Name, Upper  Position Name, Manager ID and Maneger Name-Surname(helding Upper Position ID).
2. Additionally sometimes Upperpostion may be empty and when  executing the report, it will be null. I would like to add a rule, If upperposition is null, bring 2 level upper manager

   In H_person Table 
   First Data
   *********      *********
   P_no=14556 P_ad=John 
   p_Soyad= Onel 
   P_Pzsyn= 72878 /Account Specialist 
   Second Data
   P_no=14656 
   P_ad=Sara 
   p_Soyad= Yildiz 
   P_Pzsyn= 5455 /Account Manager
   *********      *********
    In Modelorg Table 
   Pozkod=72878 
   Pozad=Account Specialist
   Ustpozkod=5455 (Account Manager) USTPOZKOD is at the same time a pozkod.
3. select p_no, p_ad, p_soyad, Pozad, USTPOZKOD (we connected pozkod to USTPOZKOD and I woul like to bring "who held this USTPOZKOD(NAME, Surname) from h_person, modelorg.
4. USTPOZKOD also equals to POZKOD because someone helds this position

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: If only SQL 2008 had some kind of hierarchyid data type....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [common table expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to build the recursive query.

An example:

```
WITH #rec AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID
    FROM RecTable
    WHERE ParentID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT R.ID, R.ParentID
    FROM RecTable R
    INNER JOIN #rec P ON R.ParentID = P.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM #rec
```

Comment: Let me give an example
In H_person Table